# MacBook Pro 2012 appearance

Tags: macbook-pro, macports, display

I just got the latest MacBook Pro (2.6 GHz i7 Quad Core, 8GB RAM, non-retina).
But the packaging and overall appearance looks just like the older 15" one (I don't see any HDMI and stuff). Are the non-retina 2012 MacBooks supposed to look like this?

Whenever I search for the unboxing/review videos of the newest model, they only review the retina one.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what your question is. Are you asking if the computer you received is the one you intended to purchase? Are you asking where to find pictures of the 2012 non-retina display MacBook Pro? What are you looking for here?

Comment: yup, it says 2.6ghz on the box, but i don't want to unwrap it and test it just in case it's a mistake and i have to return it. Some pictures of the box and the laptop iteslf would be nice

Comment: The non-retina Macbook Pro has only changed internally, non outside design changes. In fact, there aren't any design changes inside that I'm aware of. It's just a hardware upgrade inside.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's easy. The non-retina MacBook Pros didn't get a redesign on the outside. They stayed the same (so, no HDMI "and stuff"). They only got updated on the inside, so your confusion on differentiating them is reasonable.

From Apple's site - here are [images](http://www.apple.com/nl/macbook-pro/features/13-and-15-inch/) of the new 15" non-retina MacBook Pro:

[image: port side of MBP 15 2012]
[image: optical/starboard side of MBP 15 2012]

Answer (score 3):

If you want an image of the non-retina 15" 2012 MBP, Apple has one [here](http://images.apple.com/macbook-pro/features/13-and-15-inch/images/ports_15inch.jpg) as a part of [this page](http://www.apple.com/macbook-pro/features/13-and-15-inch/).

The real answer is simply open your System Information - About this Mac <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> window and see that you have a Mid 2012 model.

[image: System Information Pane]

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at the product pages on apple.com, which among other things, lists all tech specs and even has illustrated pictures of all connections and ports:

http://www.apple.com/macbook-pro/specs/13-and-15-inch/